# Why does replacing the file contents within an ArrayList return unwanted results?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, txt

How do I add the file line I have edited to the same line I got the contents from my txt file?

```
1,House mack,house,123 mack road,155,40000,40000,2022-09-29,no,Bill,123456,bill@gmail.com,12 Bill road,Jack,456789,jack@gmail.com,23 Jack road,John,789632,john@gmail.com,34 John road,
2,House John,house,123 John road,183,50000,50000,2022-09-10,yes,Bill,123456,bill@gmail.com,12 Bill road,Jack,456789,jack@gmail.com,23 Jack road,John,789632,john@gmail.com,34 John road,
```

But my output to the txt file looks like this

```
1,House mack,house,123 mack road,155,40000,111,2022-09-29,no,Bill,123456,bill@gmail.com,12 Bill road,Jack,456789,jack@gmail.com,23 Jack road,John,789632,john@gmail.com,34 John road,

1,House mack,house,123 mack road,155,40000,111,2022-09-29,no,Bill,123456,bill@gmail.com,12 Bill road,Jack,456789,jack@gmail.com,23 Jack road,John,789632,john@gmail.com,34 John road,
```

How can I get my program to only replace in the edited line in place of the old line and leave the other file contents alone?

```java
if (option.equals("cp")) {
    Array.set(values, 6, newPaid);
    findString = "\n" + values[0] + "," + values[1] + "," + values[2] + ","
        + values[3] + "," + values[4] + "," + values[5] + "," + values[6] + ","
        + values[7] + "," + values[8] + "," + values[9] + "," + values[10] + ","
        + values[11] + "," + values[12] + "," + values[13] + "," + values[14] + ","
        + values[15] + "," + values[16] + "," + values[17] + "," + values[18] + ","
        + values[19] + "," + values[20] + ",";
                                
    replaceLines(findString);
    System.out.println("Your Price has been changed and contents has been successfully updated! ");
    break;
```

My method that contains all the calculations

```java
public static void replaceLines(String findString) {
    try {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tasks.txt"));
        StringBuffer inputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
    
        while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
            line = findString; 
            inputBuffer.append(line);
            inputBuffer.append('\n');
        }
        file.close();
    
        // write the new string with the replaced line OVER the same file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("tasks.txt");
        fileOut.write(inputBuffer.toString().getBytes());
        fileOut.close();
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're in the right ballpark but should be using ```java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines```, looking for the element, replacing it and then writing out the collection again. Or use some [string list](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/40-string-list)
class that supports persistence. At the moment you're replacing *all* lines with 'findString' instead of just selected ones, or *a* selected *one*

Comment: It would also help if you explained exactly how your 'editing' is meant to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something prevalent within a specific file record has pointed you to the correct (distinct) record in order to carry out a price change, be it an ID number, a name, an Address, or whatever. You need hold whatever that is. Most would go by a distinct record ID number so that you are only changing the data within that specific record alone otherwise you could potentially change several records within the file.

Within the `replaceLines()` method, the `findString` parameter holds a new (modified) data line for the file which is to replace and existing line within the same file. The question here would be....replace what line? You don't pass that information to your method. Change the price for which person, place, or thing? This obviously needs to be determined before any changes can be carried out. For an example, let's say we want to change the price (at index 6) within the file record with an ID of `1`, the call to the `replaceLines()` method should be:

```
replaceLine( 1, findLines );
```

What would be easier is if you specified the record, the column that needs changing, and then what the new value might be for that specific column, for example:

```
updateRecord( 1, 6, "111" );
```

It could go something like this:

```
public static void updateRecord(int recordID, int recordColumnIndex, String newValue) throws IOException {
    java.io.PrintWriter writer;
    try (java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader("tasks.txt"))) {
        writer = new java.io.PrintWriter("temp.tmp");
        String line;
        // Read file line by line...
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                writer.println(line);
                continue;
            }
            // Split each read line to separate data.
            String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            
            /* If the record ID value matches the supplied ID value
               then make the desired changes to that line.    */
            if (Integer.parseInt(lineParts[0]) == recordID) {
                lineParts[recordColumnIndex] = newValue;
                // Rebuild the data line...
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(recordID));
                for (int i = 1; i < lineParts.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(",").append(lineParts[i]);
                }
                line = sb.toString();
            }
            writer.println(line);  // write line to `temp.tmp` file.
            writer.flush();        // Immediate write.
        }
    }
    writer.close();

    /* Delete the `tasks.txt` file and then rename 
       `temp.tmp` to `tasks.txt`.            */
    if (new File("tasks.txt").delete()) {
        java.nio.file.Path source = java.nio.file.Paths.get("temp.tmp");
        java.nio.file.Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling("tasks.txt"));
    }

}
```

If I'm looking at a list of records originally from the `tasks.txt` file and I can see that the record with the ID of **1** needs to have a price change in column 7  (index 6) from 40000 to 111 then I would call:

```
try {
    updateRecord(1, 6, "111");
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

**On a Side:**

Just curious, why do you start your file records with a newline (\n) character and why do you end all your records with a comma (,)??

Comment: Hi @DevilsHnd i added in the newline just to test my code, and the comma is added because I create 3 persons objects and write them to a single txt file line otherwise my output would be broken up with spaces" " inbetween the the 3 persons something like this ```Bill,123456,bill@gmail.com,12 Bill road ``` space " " and then ```Jack,456789,jack@gmail.com,23 Jack road```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation on my question

Comment: Uhhhhh....I see. Your wecome @chris.